# USB Keyboard and Mouse slow to activate using docking station for Lenovo T430

Tags: usb, keyboard, performance, thinkpad, docking-station

I just recently upgraded to a T430.   Happy with the laptop but one thing I find annoying is that when I use it through the docking station - it takes several minutes ie 3-5 for the USB keyboard and mouse plugged into the docking station to be recognized / activated.

It never used to take this long with my T410.   Any thoughts on ow I can speed this up?

Comment: I'm having this exact same thing with my T430. It didn't do it for the first year I owned it, but then it started up.